# Calculate two dates with PHP?

Tags: php, date

I have two dates in the format below:

Start Date = 30-10-2009

End Date = 30-11-2009

How, with PHP could I calculate the seconds between these two dates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parse the two dates into Unix timestamps using [`strtotime`](http://us.php.net/strtotime), then get the difference:

```
$firstTime = strtotime("30-10-2009");
$secondTime = strtotime("30-11-2009");
$diff = $secondtime - $firstTime;
```

Comment: Can unix timestamps understand any format of date I throw in, for example: 2009-30-10 ?

Comment: It's pretty good - it shouldn't have problems with `2009-30-10`. You'll need to be careful with ambiguous dates (does "10-09-2009" mean 9th October or 10th September?).

Comment: Yeah true, what would be the best format to put it in to avoid such clashes? - Thanks again

Comment: It doesn't really matter, provided you're consistent.

Answer (score 2):

The function `strtotime()` will convert a date to a unix-style timestamp (in seconds). You should then be able to subtract the end date from the start date to get the difference.

```
$difference_secs = strtotime($end_date) - strtotime($start_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather advice to use built in [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object.

```
$firstTime = new DateTime("30-10-2009");
$diff = $firstTime->diff(new DateTime("30-11-2009"));
```

As for me it's more flexible and OOP oriented.

Answer (score 1):

In fact previous answer will give you a DateInterval object but not seconds. In order to get seconds with OOP approach you should do this:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("30-10-2009");
$date2 = new DateTime("30-11-2009");
$seconds = $date2->getTimestamp() - $date1->getTimestamp();
```